# Javascript-Node.Js reaching dynamic body elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have HTML input elements with names like `A[1]`, `A[2]`, `A[3]`.  I want to catch them in express this way:

```
var optcount = i + 1;
var columnA=req.body['A['+optcount+']'];
```

However it does not work.

If I have names like `A1`, then this works:

```
var columnA=req.body['A'+optcount];
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick hack,

```
var optcount = i + 1;

var prop = 'A[' + optcount + ']';

var columnA=req.body[prop];
```

Should work.

You should be escaping characters to have a better optimized solution, look at these -> [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) and [How to escape regular expression in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript)